# UITableView scrolls to top when inserting more rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

In my code, I've overridden `tableView:willDisplayCell`, and when the last row is shown, I start a load for more data. When this data comes in, I call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` to add the rows.

This generally works (the tableview's scroll position doesn't change), but I've noticed that if I overscroll and not let go (scroll past the end of the tableview) that the tableview will jump to the top when `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is called upon data load.

I'm using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`/Autolayout for my cell heights, as each cell has different heights depending on the data they contain. How can I avoid this issue? Ideally if the data loads and the tableview is over scrolled, the scroll position would stay at the overscroll once the data comes in.

Comment: I switched from UITableViewAutomaticDimension to calculating per-row heights with a dummy cell and this issue no longer occurs. Still would like to know if it's possible to fix the issue with UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reference on the bottom cell `indexpath`, and in whichever function is causing it to go back to the top, call

`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];`

**SWIFT 3**

```
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.none, animated: true)
```

Comment: If the user was scrolled the middle of the row, wouldn't this cause the tableview to snap to the beginning of the row?

Comment: I thought this was only happening when a user over scrolls all the way to the bottom?

Comment: If so, when the new rows load, the table view would still snap to the previous last row right? The behavior I'm trying to get is the tableview staying at the overscroll position as the new data loads in the space that was previously the overscroll area. For reference, open the Facebook app and scroll to the bottom of the feed; if you overscroll the tableview will stay at the position when the posts load.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean. Perhaps you could pause the UI thread while the tableView loads, and un-pause it once the new data is ready for display...